# Linking with a g++ library fails

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc

Currently I have a shared library that is compiled with gcc and I have to build a binary (with g++) that uses this C shared library. All works fine if I compile it with gcc, no loading errors.
Now if I compile the the shared library with g++ and recompile the binary that uses the library with g++, at runtime, it complains that it can't find the library even if the paths are correct.

This is ldd output when library is compiled with gcc:

```
ldd adas_bin | grep -i ovx
/home/ubuntu/Working/bin/libOVX.so (0xf6e02000)
```

This is ldd output when compiled with g++ (the file actually exists at that path):

```
ldd adas_bin | grep -i ovx
/home/ubuntu/Working/bin/libOVX.so => not found
```

This is the output of the file command for both library versions:

```
 ELF 32-bit LSB  shared object, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked
```

When running the binary with the library compiled with g++ I get this:

```
./adasbin: error while loading shared libraries: /home/ubuntu/Working/bin/libOVX.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

What may go wrong when using the g++ version of the library ?

Comment: You don't explain how you are compiling it, is it a Makefile? What happens if you simply change the *.c* file to *.cpp* and use *gcc*. Note that *GCC* means (*GNU Compiler Collection*), you either tell *gcc* what language to use with the `-x` switch or, simply let it figure it out from the file name.

Comment: I have two separate folders each having a make file and for each version I specify which language to use: CC=g++ or CC=gcc

Comment: That's what I was trying to say *gcc* does not mean *GNU C Compiler*, but *GNU Compiler Collection*. In fact, *gcc* calls the preprocessor, then the [tag:c] compiler then the linker. If you want to specify the language use `gcc -x c` for [tag:c] and `gcc -x c++` for [tag:c++] and see what happens. But I think, you are doing something that you shouldn't. I mean, to me it's not really clear what you want to do because using *g++* instead of *gcc* as a solution doesn't seem right.

Comment: I tried the -X c++ suggestion and now at linking time I get this ugly error:



c_common.o:1:8: warning: null character(s) ignored [enabled by default]
 ELF������BؿJ�O�ۖBܿ���
        ^
c_common.o:1:1: error: stray ‘\1’ in program
 ELF������BؿJ�O�ۖBܿ���
 ^
c_common.o:1:18: warning: null character(s) ignored [enabled by default]
 ELF������BؿJ�O�ۖBܿ���
                  ^
c_common.o:1:20: warning: null character(s) ignored [enabled by default]
 ELF������B
            

cc1plus: out of memory allocating 3355443200 bytes after a total of 458752 bytes

Comment: Was it lowercase `x`?

Comment: @user1934513 looks like you are telling gcc/g++ to compile the object file as if it was source.

Comment: @iharob it was lowercase x

Comment: @davmac I did include -fpic compile flage and -shared link flag

Comment: I don't understand what your doing, but certainly you can't compile *.o* files like that. Specifying the language for *.o* files doesn't make sense at all. Can you please tell me exactly what are you trying to do?

Comment: I have some C source code that at beginning was compiled as a shared library with gcc. Now I'm trying to add some C++ code (not my decision) but before doing this I'm just trying to see if I can compile the old C code with g++ and build a shared library.

Comment: @user1934513 I don't think you're going to get a useful answer unless you supply sufficient information in your question. The content of the Makefiles that you are using, for example, would help, but it would probably be better to reduce this to a simple test case with a sequence of commands that you type manually, that reproduces the problem. If you do that and include the commands in your question, someone maybe can help.